# create multiple rows from a given json in Python

Tags: python

Input json:

```
[{'EmpID': 14,
  'EempType': 'Temp',
  'Initials': 'John',
  'LastUpdateAuthor': 'John',
  'S_time': '72',
  'I_time': '37',
  'N_time': '35'},
{'EmpID': 14,
  'EempType': 'Temp',
  'Initials': 'John',
  'LastUpdateAuthor': 'John',
  'S_time': '96',
  'I_time': '37',
  'N_time': '33'},
{'EmpID': 14,
  'EempType': 'Perm',
  'Initials': 'Jock',
  'LastUpdateAuthor': 'Jock',
  'S_time': '192',
  'I_time': '7.0',
  'N_time': '6.80'},
{'EmpID': 17,
  'EempType': 'Temp',
  'Initials': 'Mag',
  'LastUpdateAuthor': 'Mag',
  'S_time': '0',
  'I_time': '37',
  'N_time': ''},
{'EmpID': 17,
  'EempType': 'Temp',
  'Initials': 'Mag',
  'LastUpdateAuthor': 'Mag',
  'S_time': '24',
  'I_time': '37',
  'N_time': '35'},
{'EmpID': 17,
  'EempType': 'Temp',
  'Initials': 'Mag',
  'LastUpdateAuthor': 'Mag',
  'S_time': '48',
  'I_time': '37',
  'N_time': '33'},
]
```

Desired output should be like this for ppoint and tpoint:

[image]

for better understanding, I have mentioned the input use cases,

[image]

This is my code and it is not working as expected for all cases. Not sure what is the issue with my code.

```
out = []
default_value = 0

out.append({"RunID":json_data[0]["empID"], "empType":json_data[0]["empType"],"ppoint": json_data[0]["I_time"], "target_duration":default_value})

for a in json_data[1:]:
  out.append({"empID": a["empID"], "empType": a["empType"],"ppoint": a["N_time"], "tpoint": a["S_time"]})

out

df = pd.DataFrame(out)
df
```

correct me pls.

Comment: I suppose you are parsing yout json string with `JSON` lib. You might have more success using pandas `read_json` function ([link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html)) and manipulating your dataframe from there.

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame(json_data)` ?

Comment: can you plesae give more info about json_normalize? how to related to it ? 
Thanks

Comment: You can simply call the `pd.DataFrame` constructor (*check the dup fo more details*).

Comment: but it just create a DF. but how can we handle out put?

Answer (score 0):

In your loop and your header for appending rows to `out` your keys don't match your provided data source. Here's an example based upon the for loop..  `a["empID"]` should be `a["EmpID"]` and `a["emptype"]` should be `a["Eemptype"]`
You have the same error in your header row processing.  This is going to likely cause significant problems.

Comment: Actually it is working for 2 rows which has same empID and Shifttype. 
If I have only one record it is not working.

Comment: can't be right based in the input json you gave and the code you provided. I can't see the images.   it's also unclear why you are treating the very first row differently then all the others.

Comment: if you have only one record its going to raise an out of bounds exception for your attempt to access an out of bounds index in the array slicing of your for loop.  You should protect it with a size check **but that isn't the example you provided**  dont ask multiple questions, ask a single question you asked about the input you provided us.